# Catch Null value use a Foreach statement in an string array Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, null

```
public void GrantAccesOnPage(int AccessPoint1, int AccessPoint2) 
        {
            GlobalVariables.GrantDeny = 0;
            string[] arr = { 
                               GlobalVariables.SessionPort1, 
                               GlobalVariables.SessionPort2, 
                               GlobalVariables.SessionPort3, 
                               GlobalVariables.SessionPort4 
                           };
            foreach (var r in arr)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(r) == AccessPoint1 || Convert.ToInt32(r) == AccessPoint2)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.ToString()))
                    {
                        GlobalVariables.GrantDeny = 1;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        throw new System.ArgumentException("Null");
                    }
                }
            }
            if (GlobalVariables.GrantDeny != 1)
            {
                Response.Redirect("PageNotAccessable.aspx");
            }
        }
```

i tried Converting each "Var" in my "r" foreach statment to string or int but still doesn't catch the null value tried a throw exception too it won't skip if its null it stops the page into an error view. please help..

Comment: Enable exceptions and find the problem where it breaks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Your code doesn't make much sense IMO, you attempt to convert r to an `int` but do not use the return value of the Convert method, then you check if the string `r` is null or empty?

Comment: Its ok sir how stupid of me to not figure it out.. i'm sorry its a boolean condition and i just want to skip it if its null same as the condition of the first if i got it now.. i'm suppose to use a "r != null" i was converting the var thats why its doesn't get any exact answer.. sorry its ok now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check IsNull first:

```
public void GrantAccesOnPage(int AccessPoint1, int AccessPoint2) 
        {
            GlobalVariables.GrantDeny = 0;
            string[] arr = { 
                               GlobalVariables.SessionPort1, 
                               GlobalVariables.SessionPort2, 
                               GlobalVariables.SessionPort3, 
                               GlobalVariables.SessionPort4 
                           };
            foreach (var r in arr)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(r))
                {
                    //remove the comment out only if you want to throw the exception. 
                    //throw new System.ArgumentException("Null");  
                }
                else
                {    
                   if (Convert.ToInt32(r) == AccessPoint1 || Convert.ToInt32(r) == AccessPoint2)
                   {
                        GlobalVariables.GrantDeny = 1;                    
                   }
                }
            }
            if (GlobalVariables.GrantDeny != 1)
            {
               Response.Redirect("PageNotAccessable.aspx");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Also note that Convert.ToInt32() on a null string will result in 0. AccessPoint1 and AccessPoint2 is not 0, hence why the original code didn't work.

Comment: sir i tried a break point on the "throw new " cause it returns error how do i skip it like the else statement when its a null?? like ignore the variables same as the else condition if its not equal it skips it. cause when it comes to a null it shows an error page. like its just suppose to go by the process skip if its a null or not equal value.

Comment: @Oblivious7, you want to throw the exception or just simply want to skip it? I'm a little bit lost here, if you want to skip the error, just remove the line: `throw new System.ArgumentException("Null");`